# Google Sheets: Find a Row that Matches Only a Few Specific Characteristics

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't seem to find the right equation to find a cell from a row that matches only a few specific characteristics. In this example, I am trying to find the equation for Column D which would be the cell in A that has the same cells for B & C.
[image]

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: There are still unknowns here, Brett. What should happen if there is more than one match possible in Column D (e.g., if "Bob Smith" also had "Apple" in Column C)? Or is that never going to be a possibility? And must Column D say "None" if there is no match, or is a null return OK? It would also help move things along if you could provide a link to a sheet with a realistic set of sample data already in it

Comment: Good points, @ErikTyler.
More than result should never be possible with my data. Column D can say anything for no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide two options.

If you're sure your data will only ever have zero or one match, you can place the following formula into D2 of an otherwise empty range D2:D...

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C,{B2:B&C2:C,A2:A},2,FALSE)&VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C,SORT({B2:B&C2:C,A2:A,ROW(A2:A)},3,0),2,FALSE),A2:A,"")))`

However, if you think more than one match may turn up and you want "None" to be returned if there is no match, you can use the following formula in D2 or an otherwise empty range D2:D...

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C,TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({B2:B&C2:C&"~",A2:A&","}, "Select MAX(Col2) where Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1"),, 9^9)),"~")),2,FALSE),A2:A,""),"^[,\s]+$","None"),"([^,\s].+[^,\s])[,\s]*$"),"[,\s]+",", ")))`

The second formula will work even if there will only ever be zero or one match; it's just not necessary to have it be that lengthy. And the second formula is only as lengthy because it was unclear from your posted examples whether the data in Col A, B and C will *really* only ever be one word or not; so the formula is built to assume there will *not* always be one-word strings in those columns.

Either formula will provide results for the entire column without dragging.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option, You can use this formula in column D2:

```
=iferror(textjoin(", ",true,query($A$2:$C,"Select A where A is not null and A != '"&$A2&"' and B = '"&$B2&"' and C = '"&$C2&"'",0)),"None")
```

**Limitation:**

- You need to manually drag the formula to its succeeding rows. Arrayformula() cannot be used in looping the query string values.

### What it does?

- Using [query()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), filter the data from A2:C that has the same current row last name(Column B) and food(Column C) at the same time having a different first name(Column A)
- If there are multiple results, use [textjoin()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en) to combine them with `", "` as its delimiter.
- If there is no matched found, it will return an error, hence use [iferror()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) to set the default value to "None"

### Output

[image]